# Why am I stuck in an extra long for-loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I know I'm being a little dumb about this, but I figured id take a break for a few mins and ask this question. I'm trying to add a countdown feature to an input box. The problem is that its doing the input amount a squared number of times when all im really trying to is increment a variable thats called inside the loop itself. I'm certain it will come to me, but getting someone else perspective helps.

```
String propertyNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Numer of Properties...");
int propNumber = Integer.parseInt(propertyNumber);
numOfProperties = new float[propNumber];

for(int i= 0; i < propNumber; i++) {
    for(int a = propNumber; a >= 0; a--) {
        String propertyVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter each property value for the " + propNumber + " Properties you listed. You have " + a + " inputs left.");
        numOfProperties[i] = Float.parseFloat(propertyVal); //takes property value info and stores them inside the property number array
    }
}
```

Comment: Terminates fine for me. Not sure why you have the outer loop though. Did you debug this code?

Comment: Your loop is not infinite, you just prompt for `propNumber` properties `propNumber`² times. Why did you nest the loop? `int a = propNumber - i;` and one loop (is what I *think* you wanted).

Comment: Just realized I framed the question wrong. My issue is - that whenever I enter, say 3, properties. It will run the loop 9 times. I think its because im counting the variable 'propNumber' twice in the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, *propNumber = 3*. Since, you are using nested loops it will work as follows :

Take the case of the nested loop first :

```
for(int a = propNumber; a >= 0; a--) {

}
```

Given propNumber is 3, the code inside it will be executed 3 times.

Take the case of the main loop :

```
for(int i= 0; i < propNumber; i++) {
    //another loop inside
}
```

As the code inside the main loop will be executed 3 times, the loop inside it will get executed 3 times as well. 3*3 = 9.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you do not need a nested loop. I believe you want a single loop and `a` should be calculated from the number of properties and the current index `i`. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < propNumber; i++) {
    int a = propNumber - i;
    String propertyVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter each property value for the "
            + propNumber + " Properties you listed. You have " + a + " inputs left.");
    numOfProperties[i] = Float.parseFloat(propertyVal); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely overlooked the fact that I should have just declared a variable inside the for-loop and utilized the initialized variable to work with it.